# update png's automatically in Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

I wonder if there's a setting for letting PNG's that you've added to your canvas be updated if the original file is updated? Now when I add a PNG to the canvas it creates an image copy of the original PNG, I don't want that, I want the image to be linked to the original PNG so that any updates to the PNG are also updated to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sketch unfortunately does not support this out of the box.

However, there is a Sketch [plugin](https://github.com/frankko/Place-Linked-Bitmap?utm_source=designernews) that keeps track of the source location of images placed into a Sketch file and allows them to be updated with one click.

Comment: @AndroidHustle glad I could be of help! :)